# Searching through large list of elements

Tags: jquery, performance, search

I have a list of Destination projects, and source projects that have a Project, Feature, and Milestone Associated. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Q63Dx/7/)

As my list is quite large (around 4000 elements in total), I made the source projects belonging to the destination projects collapsible to compact the space and help readability.

Sample markup:

```
<div class='projectscontainer'>
    <div id="destarrow" class="arrow-right"></div>
    <span class="item destproject unselectable" title="ID: 426">Kzax-Xrj</span>
    <br>
    <div class="srcprojects" style="display: block; margin-left: 30px;">
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 4760">Lokhxtea</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="srcprojects" style="display: block; margin-left: 30px;">
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 4760">Zbjamjh</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="srcprojects" style="display: block; margin-left: 30px;">
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 6034">Jeuzax-Xrjamjhxteaq</span>
        <div id='arrow' class='arrow-right'></div>
        <span class='item srcproject exception' title='Project'>Qiospq</span>
        <div id='arrow' class='arrow-right'></div>
        <span class='item srcproject exception' title='Feature'>Qiospq</span>
        <div id='arrow' class='arrow-right'></div>
        <span class='item srcproject exception' title='Milestone'>Muqewko</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I collapsed all the source projects, it is hard to find a specific source project.

How can I create a simple filter in jQuery that can locate certain destination/source projects using an input? I have tried something like [jQuery Fast Live Filter](http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/) but it doesn't seem to work for my markup.

Also, as I have 4000 or so of these source projects, the expanding and collapsing of Destination projects feels a bit unresponsive (slow). Are there any fixes I can apply to my existing jQuery (in the JSFiddle) that will help with that?

Comment: Iterating through 4000 elements isn't really that horrible. I would _strongly_ consider using an object for a project instead of a DOM element and doing all the logic there. When your representation and data are one stuff gets really messy really fast. Searching through a sorted list is O(logn) (for example, binary search). Even if your list isn't sorted, it's still just O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because jQuery Fast Live Filter works on a single level and your project is using multiple levels of nesting. You will have to roll your own. It should not be that hard : https://github.com/awbush/jquery-fastLiveFilter/blob/master/jquery.fastLiveFilter.js

All you have to do is modify the function in input.change based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your second question, you might find slight performance advantages by selecting the elements differently, though I don't think any improvements will be great.

You could try this, for example:

```
$('.projectscontainer').on("click", "span.destproject", function () {
    $(this).siblings('.srcprojects').toggle().end().siblings('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
}).on("click", "div.destarrow", function () {
    $(this).parent().find("span.destproject").trigger("click");
});
```

Note: `destarrow` is changed from an ID to a class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q63Dx/8/